# PHP: Retornar valor anterior da variável em loop "for"

Tags: php

Tenho um loop "for" em PHP da seguinte maneira

```
$max = 10; 

for($i = 0; $i <= $max; $i++){
  $var1 = $i * 100;
  $var2 = var1  * 50;
  $var3 = (MINHA_DUVIDA_AQUI);
}
```

Em `$var3` eu gostaria de retornar o valor da `$var3` da *row* anterior, por exemplo, se estou em `$i = 3`, preciso que a `$var3` seja igual a `$var2` do $i = 2.

Tentei com a função `prev()`, mas por não ser um *array* não funcionou.

Alguma dica de como resolver essa situação?

Comment: Você pode fazer $var2 = ($i-1) * 50. Seria esse seu problema pelo o que entendi.

Comment: Só precisa tratar essa situação quando o $i = 0. Nesse caso não sei o que deseja retornar, mas pode verificar se o $i == 0 então $var2 = 0, e caso não seja igual 0 calcular conforme meu comentário de cima.

Comment: O problema é que minha "var2" já é resultado de outro calculo na linha anterior

Comment: Basta fazer $var3 = $var2 ANTES do $var2 = formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta fazer `$var3 = $var2` ANTES do `$var2 = formula`

```
$max = 10; 
$var2 = 0;

for($i = 0; $i <= $max; $i++){
  $var3 = $var2; // Neste momento o $var2 ainda não pegou a linha atual
                 // consequentemente, terá sempre o valor da linha anterior
                 // ou zero, na primeira iteração (já que definimos zero fora do loop)
  $var1 = $i * 100;
  $var2 = $var1 * 50;

  // Agora já temos $var1, $var2 e $var3 definidos, sendo que 1 e 2 são
  // da linha corrente, e o 3 da anterior
  echo '$var1:' . $var1 . ' - $var2:' . $var2 . ' - $var3:' . $var3;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/5VGyXV)**.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente